# Complex validation rule in Microsoft access

Tags: validation, ms-access

I want to have a complex validation rule in Microsoft access. The string should be 9 digits and validate with the following formula.

For example, if the string is ABCDEFGHI:

(9 x A) + (8 x B) + (7 x C) + (6 x D) + (5 x E) + (4 x F) + (3 x G) + (2 x H) + (-1 x I) % 11 == 0.

Can I use this as a validation rule or should I use code for it? If I have to use code, how would I have to do it?

Comment: You haven't given us much to work with. Is this being entered into a text box? Are you multiplying numbers by characters?

Comment: Please expand on this if possible.  Is the string you entered (ABCDEFGHI) supposed to be numbers?  You can't multiply 9 times a letter, unless you meant you want the letter to show up 9 times?  Are you getting this string from a textbox?  There is a **lot** of confusion here, we ned more to go on if you want an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is entered in a text field in a form. The letters represent numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab at thi sand edit later if necessary, but I'm going to have to make several assumptions since the information isn't really explicit in the question.

Assume you're entering this 9-digit number into a textbox.  I woul dput this in the AfterUpdate event of the textbox:

```
Val1 = CInt(Left(MyTextBox.Text, 1)
Val2 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 2, 1)
Val3 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 3, 1)
Val4 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 4, 1)
Val5 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 5, 1)
Val6 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 6, 1)
Val7 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 7, 1)
Val8 = CInt(Mid(MyTextBox.Text, 8, 1)
Val9 = CInt(Rightt(MyTextBox.Text, 1)

If ((9 x Val1) + (8 x Val2) + (7 x Val3) + (6 x Val4) + (5 x Val5) + (4 x Val6) + 
    (3 x Val7) + (2 x Val8) + (-1 x Val9) % 11) = 0 Then
  'Whatever it is you want to do
Else
  'Whatever should be done if the validation fails
End If
```

This will give you a lot more control over messages and functionality you might want to perform depending on the outcome of the If/Then statement.